# Using different parts of rss feed in a universal app using mvvmcross and commands

Tags: c#, rss, win-universal-app, mvvmcross, windows-10-universal

So i've been trying to build a simple rss feed app for win10 using universal apps and mvvmcross that will do the following:

- Load all items from an address in a listbox or something similar which will show them in the splitview.
- When clicking on a title it will open a WebView with the full article of the specific title.

The problem I have, is binding different parts of the same RssItems to different controls but keep their relation. I'm new to both technologies but i think it should be possible somehow, I just can't find the way.

These are the related parts of the code I wrote:

viewModel.cs:

```
class FirstViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    private List<string> _rssItems;

    public List<string> RssItems
    {
        get { return _rssItems; }
        set { _rssItems = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => RssItems); }
    }

    public MvxCommand SelectionChangedCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new MvxCommand(() =>
            {
                LoadRssItems();
            });
        }
    }

    private async void LoadRssItems()
    {
        List<string> feedItems = new List<string>();
        SyndicationClient rssReaderClient = new SyndicationClient();
        SyndicationFeed rssFeed = await rssReaderClient.RetrieveFeedAsync(new Uri("xml address"));

        if (rssFeed != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in rssFeed.Items)
            {
                feedItems.Add(item.Title.Text);
                RssItemsOrinigal.Add(item);
            }

            RssItems = feedItems;
        }
    }
```

And the firstView.xaml:

```
<views:MvxWindowsPage
    x:Class="RssReader.Views.FirstView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:RssReader.Views"
    xmlns:views="using:MvvmCross.WindowsUWP.Views"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <RelativePanel>
            <Button x:Name="HamburgerButton"
                    RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
                    FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                    FontSize="36"
                    Content="&#xE700;"
                    Click="HamburgerButton_Click"/>

        <SplitView Grid.Row="1"
                   x:Name="sv"
                   DisplayMode="CompactOverlay"
                   OpenPaneLength="200"
                   CompactPaneLength="50">

            <SplitView.Pane>
                <ListBox x:Name="lstMenuItems" SelectionMode="Single">
                    <ListBoxItem x:Name="ListBoxItem1">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Button FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="36" Command="{Binding SelectionChangedCommand}">&#xE14A;</Button>
                            <TextBlock FontSize="24" Text="Website 1" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListBoxItem>                    
                </ListBox>
            </SplitView.Pane>
            <SplitView.Content>
                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding RssItems}"/>
            </SplitView.Content>
        </SplitView>

    </Grid>
</views:MvxWindowsPage>
```

Comment: I'm a little confused, you showed only one `ListBoxItem` in the Pane of `SplitView` and the entire `ListBox` in the Content of `SplitView`, where do you want to hold a `WebView` for details? In another page? Or you want to show the title of entire `ListBox` in the Pane and show details with `WebView` in content of `SplitView`?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/HZFQi this is how it looks.
when pressing on one of the titles, i want a WebView to replace the list with the site showing the correct link of the said title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is using [ContentPresenter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentpresenter.aspx) together with your `ListBox` and set the `Visibility` property each time when you select an item or want to go back to the `ListBox`:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DetailContent">
        <WebView Source="{Binding DetailUri}" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ListBoxContent">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>

...
<SplitView.Content>
    <Grid>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{x:Bind listBox.SelectedItem, Mode=OneWay}"
                          ContentTemplate="{StaticResource DetailContent}" Visibility="{x:Bind VM.IsVisible, Mode=OneWay}" />
        <ListBox x:Name="listBox" ItemsSource="{x:Bind VM.RssItems}"
                 ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListBoxContent}" SelectionChanged="{x:Bind VM.listBox_SelectionChanged}" />
        <Button Content="Close and Show ListBox" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Visibility="{x:Bind VM.IsVisible, Mode=OneWay}"
                Click="{x:Bind VM.IsVisible_Clicked}" />
    </Grid>
</SplitView.Content>
```

In the ViewModel of this page for example:

```
public class Page6ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<ListBoxDetail> RssItems;

    private Visibility _IsVisible = Visibility.Collapsed;

    public Visibility IsVisible
    {
        get { return _IsVisible; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _IsVisible)
            {
                _IsVisible = value;
                OnpropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public Page6ViewModel()
    {
        RssItems = new ObservableCollection<ListBoxDetail>();
        RssItems.Add(new ListBoxDetail { Title = "Item 1", DetailUri = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38853708/using-different-parts-of-rss-feed-in-a-universal-app-using-mvvmcross-and-command?noredirect=1#comment65137456_38853708" });
        RssItems.Add(new ListBoxDetail { Title = "Item 2", DetailUri = "https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ms668604(v=vs.105).aspx" });
        RssItems.Add(new ListBoxDetail { Title = "Item 3", DetailUri = "https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource.aspx" });
    }

    private ListBox listBox;

    public void listBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        listBox = sender as ListBox;
        listBox.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        IsVisible = Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public void IsVisible_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        listBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        IsVisible = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnpropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Another common method is using [Frame](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame.aspx) as `Content` of `SpiltView`, then create a page for `ListBox` and a page for `WebView`, at first navigate this frame to the page of `ListBox`, in the `SelectionChanged` event, you can send the uri as parameter and navigate this frame to the page of `WebView`. For this method, there are many samples on the internet and you can search for them.

Comment: your suggestion of using visibility as bool is sound but the way isn't. in universal apps+mvvmcross you're supposed to use  MvxCommands in code and with the command bind in the xaml, not button click and other events like it.

Comment: @ThatOneGuy, yes you're right, as you can see from my code, I'm not using mvvmcross, or template 10, or mvvm light or prims 6, it's absolutely right to bind command in the xaml, but I just provided a basic sample to explain how to use `ContentPresenter` to bind different parts, using Click event to bind or using command, not a big problem I think?